# Click not working with hover image with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Still learning jQuery, but came across an issue. I have a "div" with an image in it and clickable. However, I added a transparent image as a hover, and now the div is not clickable where the image is. Is there a way to make the hover clickable as well?

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <img src="kittens.jpg">
    <img class="hover" src="hover.png">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.box').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find('img.hover').show();
    },
    function() {
        $(this).find('img.hover').hide();
    }
);
```

Comment: Show your click handler.

Comment: Why don't you bind the click to your hover image as well/instead?

Comment: @scrowler, how would I go about binding? $('box').on('click, hover')?

Comment: `$('.box').on('click', yourfunction); $('img.hover').on('click', yourfunction); function yourfunction(clicked){ alert(clicked); }`